# Wordpress ACF repeater field and Bootstrap modal

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-modal, acfpro

I am using Bootstrap tabs to display a grid with employee profiles and photo's in ACF repeater fields and when clicking on the profile a bootstrap modal pops up with the information filled out in a repeater sub field.

Everything is working fine, but when you click on the different profiles, the same profile information is in the modal and not different profile information.

Here is my code

```
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">

        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="team" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="team-tab">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-between">

<?php 
if( have_rows('team_profile_boxes') ):
    $i = 1;

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('team_profile_boxes') ) : the_row(); ?>

                    <div id="profile-box">
                        <div class="profile-image-box">
                            <div class="profile-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo the_sub_field('profile_image'); ?>');"></div>
                            <div class="profile-image-hover" style="background-image: url('<?php echo the_sub_field('second_profile_image'); ?>');"></div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="profile-details">
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModal">
                                <h4>
                                    <span><?php the_sub_field('division_title'); ?></span>
                                    <br>
                                    <?php the_sub_field('profile_name'); ?> <br>
                                    <span><?php the_sub_field('job_title'); ?></span>
                                </h4>
                            </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <?php the_sub_field('profile_information'); ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<?php  $i++;

    endwhile;

else :

    // no rows found

endif;
?>
</div>
</div>
```

I've looked through this example but it doesn't seem to apply:
[ACF Repeater + Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746254/acf-repeater-modal)

Answer (score 0):

you have not print `$i` ,  try this code ...

```
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="team" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="team-tab">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-between">

            <?php 
            if( have_rows('team_profile_boxes') ):
                $i = 1;

                // loop through the rows of data
                while ( have_rows('team_profile_boxes') ) : the_row(); ?>

                    <div id="profile-box-<?php echo $i; ?>">

                        <?php //your code ?>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal fade" id="profile-box-<?php echo $i; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

                        <?php //your code ?>

                    </div>

                <?php  $i++;

                endwhile;

            else :

            // no rows found

            endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That really didn't work, took out styling and removed the modal functionality

Answer (score 0):

you can use an acf build-in function called **get_row_index()** to set an index to all the rows. it starts from 1 and goes up to end of your rows count.

```
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="team" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="team-tab">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-between">
    <?php if( have_rows('team_profile_boxes') ):
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('team_profile_boxes') ) : the_row(); $i = get_row_index();?>
        <div id="profile-box">
            <div class="profile-image-box">
                <div class="profile-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo the_sub_field('profile_image'); ?>');"></div>
                <div class="profile-image-hover" style="background-image: url('<?php echo the_sub_field('second_profile_image'); ?>');"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="profile-details">
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModal-<?php echo $i;?>">
                    <h4>
                        <span><?php the_sub_field('division_title'); ?></span>
                        <br>
                        <?php the_sub_field('profile_name'); ?> <br>
                        <span><?php the_sub_field('job_title'); ?></span>
                    </h4>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal-<?php echo $i;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <?php the_sub_field('profile_information'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't work, took out the styling and no modal functionality

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it using the philosophy above but using the following code:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="team" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="team-tab">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-between">
<?php 
if( have_rows('team_profile_boxes') ):
    $i = 1;
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('team_profile_boxes') ) : the_row(); ?>
                    <div id="profile-box">
                        <div class="profile-image-box">
                            <div class="profile-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo the_sub_field('profile_image'); ?>');"></div>
                            <div class="profile-image-hover" style="background-image: url('<?php echo the_sub_field('second_profile_image'); ?>');"></div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="profile-details">
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="<?php echo '#exampleModal' . $i ?>">
                                <h4>
                                    <span><?php the_sub_field('division_title'); ?></span>
                                    <br>
                                    <?php the_sub_field('profile_name'); ?> <br>
                                    <span><?php the_sub_field('job_title'); ?></span>
                                </h4>
                            </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo 'exampleModal' . $i ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <?php the_sub_field('profile_information'); ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<?php  $i++;
    endwhile;
else :
    // no rows found
endif;
?>
</div>
</div>
```